# Head Pose Estimation on Random Forest in G Fanelli's paper

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I have been working on head pose estimation on depth data. And I have read G Fanelli's paper-"Real Time Head Pose Estimation from Consumer Depth Cameras" "Real Time Head Pose Estimation with Random Regression Forests". I test the data and the code Fanelli published on the website(http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gfanelli/head_pose/head_forest.html). However when I run the code, there is a problem. ***The error information is "usage: ./head_pose_estimation config_file depth_image"***. I think it is about file reading but I don't how to fix it.

and the code is like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( argc != 3 )
    {
        cout << "usage: ./head_pose_estimation config_file depth_image" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    loadConfig(argv[1]);
    CRForestEstimator estimator;
    if( !estimator.loadForest(g_treepath.c_str(), g_ntrees) ){

        cerr << "could not read forest!" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    string depth_fname(argv[2]);

    //read calibration file (should be in the same directory as the depth image!)
    string cal_filename = depth_fname.substr(0,depth_fname.find_last_of("/")+1);
    cal_filename += "depth.cal";
    ifstream is(cal_filename.c_str());
    if (!is){
        cerr << "depth.cal file not found in the same folder as the depth image! " << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //read intrinsics only
    float depth_intrinsic[9];   for(int i =0; i<9; ++i) is >> depth_intrinsic[i];
    is.close();

    Mat depthImg;
    //read depth image (compressed!)
    if (!loadDepthImageCompressed( depthImg, depth_fname.c_str() ))
        return -1;

    Mat img3D;
    img3D.create( depthImg.rows, depthImg.cols, CV_32FC3 );

    //get 3D from depth
    for(int y = 0; y < img3D.rows; y++)
    {
        Vec3f* img3Di = img3D.ptr<Vec3f>(y);
        const int16_t* depthImgi = depthImg.ptr<int16_t>(y);

        for(int x = 0; x < img3D.cols; x++){

            float d = (float)depthImgi[x];

            if ( d < g_max_z && d > 0 ){

                img3Di[x][0] = d * (float(x) - depth_intrinsic[2])/depth_intrinsic[0];
                img3Di[x][1] = d * (float(y) - depth_intrinsic[5])/depth_intrinsic[4];
                img3Di[x][2] = d;
            }
            else{

                img3Di[x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    g_means.clear();
    g_votes.clear();
    g_clusters.clear();

    string pose_filename(depth_fname.substr(0,depth_fname.find_last_of('_')));
    pose_filename += "_pose.bin";

    cv::Vec<float,POSE_SIZE> gt;
    bool have_gt = false;
    //try to read in the ground truth from a binary file
    FILE* pFile = fopen(pose_filename.c_str(), "rb");
    if(pFile){

        have_gt = true;
        have_gt &= ( fread( &gt[0], sizeof(float),POSE_SIZE, pFile) == POSE_SIZE );
        fclose(pFile);
    }

    //do the actual estimate
    estimator.estimate(     img3D,
                            g_means,
                            g_clusters,
                            g_votes,
                            g_stride,
                            g_maxv,
                            g_prob_th,
                            g_larger_radius_ratio,
                            g_smaller_radius_ratio,
                            false,
                            g_th
                        );

    cout << "Heads found : " << g_means.size() << endl;

    //assuming there's only one head in the image!
    if(g_means.size()>0){

        cout << "Estimated: " << g_means[0][0] << " " << g_means[0][1] << " " << g_means[0][2] << " " << g_means[0][3] << " " << g_means[0][4] << " " << g_means[0][5] <<endl;

        float pt2d_est[2];
        float pt2d_gt[2];

        if(have_gt){
            cout << "Ground T.: " << gt[0] << " " << gt[1] << " " << gt[2] << " " << gt[3] << " " << gt[4] << " " << gt[5] <<endl;

            cv::Vec<float,POSE_SIZE> err = (gt-g_means[0]);
            //multiply(err,err,err);
            for(int n=0;n<POSE_SIZE;++n)
                err[n] = err[n]*err[n];

            float h_err = sqrt(err[0]+err[1]+err[2]);
            float a_err = sqrt(err[3]+err[4]+err[5]);

            cout << "Head error : " << h_err << " mm " << endl;
            cout << "Angle error : " << a_err <<" degrees " <<  endl;

            pt2d_gt[0] = depth_intrinsic[0]*gt[0]/gt[2] + depth_intrinsic[2];
            pt2d_gt[1] = depth_intrinsic[4]*gt[1]/gt[2] + depth_intrinsic[5];
        }

        pt2d_est[0] = depth_intrinsic[0]*g_means[0][0]/g_means[0][2] + depth_intrinsic[2];
        pt2d_est[1] = depth_intrinsic[4]*g_means[0][1]/g_means[0][2] + depth_intrinsic[5];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone could tell me how to fix the problem?Thanks so much!

Comment: How are you running the code? By the look of it you need two parameters (`if( argc != 3 )` - remember first parameter is the command name) - a config file and an image file. If you're running from an IDE such as Visual Studio, there will be an option to set command line parameters when running the code.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 as an IDE. And I have been load a config file and an image file, but after running the code, there is no option for me to set command line parameters, just "Press any key to continue".

Answer (score 1):

You should always read the readme.txt (here attached in `head_pose_estimation.tgz`) before testing an application:

> To run the example code, type `./head_pose_estimation config.txt
>   data/frame_XXXX_depth.bin`. The `config.txt` file contains all parameters
>   needed for the head pose estimation, e.g., the path to the forest, the
>   stride, and `z` threshold used to segment the person from the
>   background.